# Minkowski's theorem generalization

Tags: measure-theory, algebraic-number-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let  $\Omega$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with $\mu(\Omega) > n$. Then there exists $p \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $|(\Omega + p) \cap \mathbb Z^n| \geq n+1$. In other words, some translate of $\Omega$ contains at least $n+1$ points with only integer coordinates.

The way to do this would be by contradiction, but I have a doubt I'd like to clear anyway.

Let's define $x\sim y$ in $\mathbb R^n$ if $x - y \in \mathbb Z^n$. This is an equivalence relation. Now, note that if there exists $y$ such that $[y] \cap \Omega$ has more than $n+1$ points, then we are done.

Note that for all $y$ , there is a unique $x \in B := [0,1) \times ...\times [0,1)$ such that $x \sim y$.

Let's assume the contrary of the conclusion. This means, that for all $x \in B$, we have $|[x] \cap \Omega| \leq n$.

This allows us to define an surjective map from $S := \cup_{i=0}^{n-1} (B + (i,0,...,0)) \to \Omega$ (the left hand set is just $[0,n) \times [0,1) \times ... \times [0,1)$) as follows: for each $x \in \Omega$ we have $[x] \cap \Omega = \{x = x_0,...,x_{k-1}\}$ , where $k \leq n$, now just map $[y] + (i,...,0) \to x_i$ where $y \in B$ is the unique $[y] = [x]$.

Basically, I've sort of indexed the translates of every point in $\Omega$ using the set $S$.

If we can show that this map is measurable, than $\Omega$ has volume smaller than $S$, which means that its volume is less  than or equal to $n$, contradiction.

> But how do I show that the above map is measurable? Also , this proof does not use the fact that $\Omega$ is compact, so is there something that I am missing?

Note :As a generalization of Minkowski's theorem, I think the tag "algebraic number theory" suits this question also.

Comment: Note that the theorem is false for $[0,k)\times[0,k)$

Comment: Oh, I misread - I thought the first sentence read $\mu(\Omega)=n$, not $\mu(\Omega)>n$. (Are you sure that wasn't a typo, by the way?)

Comment: That is not a typo : I think the statement given is correct. But I can assume that $\Omega$ is compact, because of inner regularity of the Lebesgue measure. This may help. That is to say, now I think that the statement is true for unbounded $\Omega$, and this follows by taking a compact subset with very little measure difference from $\Omega$ and using the above result.

Comment: I think they're both correct, but the version with $=$ is stronger.

Comment: However, I am still wondering whether the above proof goes through or not. Certainly, the map sends every point to another point in the same equivalence class : does this qualify for measurability? For my purposes,the weaker version suffices, so I will stick to proving it. If the weaker version doesn't work out with a similar proof, I will post it in another question.

Comment: How are you defining $x_i$? (In other words, what order are you putting on $x_0,\dots,x_{k-1}$?)

Comment: I am wondering if the order matters. For the sake of it, let it be lexicographic i.e. first compare the first coordinates, then the second coordinates if the first match. Also, you may assume $\Omega$ is compact and try to see if a different map can be made which is easier to work with, maybe using the fact that $\Omega$ intersects only finitely many hypercubes of the lattice.

Comment: I think that if we can show that the set of points $x\in\Omega$ such that $x=x_0$ (that is, such that $x$ is first in the ordering on $[x]$) is measurable, then we can show that the function $S$ is measurable. Call this set $\Omega_0$; I think we can write $\Omega_0$ as the union of simpler sets. I'll see if I can write it out later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a proof of your statement.

I'll change $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^k$ (I believe that you didn't intend the dimension to be equal to $n$ in question).

Denote $m = \sup_{p\in\mathbb R^k} |(\Omega + p)\cap \mathbb{Z}^k|$ and $d = \lceil\mathrm{diam}(\Omega)\rceil$. Let $N\in \mathbb{N}$ and consider $A=[0,N)^k-\Omega = \{x-y\mid x\in [0,N)^k,y\in\Omega\}$. Clearly, $\mu(A)\le (N+d)^k$. Then, denoting $T =[0,N)\cap \mathbb{Z}^k$,
$$
\int_{A}\sum_{x\in T}\mathbf{1}_{\Omega + p}(x) dp \le \int_{A}\big|(\Omega + p)\cap \mathbb{Z}^k\big| dp \le m \mu(A)\le m(N+d)^k.
$$
However, using that $-\Omega+x \subset A$ for any $x\in T$, we have
$$
\int_{A}\sum_{x\in T}\mathbf{1}_{\Omega + p}(x) dp = \sum_{x\in T}\int_{A}\mathbf{1}_{-\Omega + x}(p) dp = \sum_{x\in T} \mu\big((-\Omega+x)\cap A\big)\\
= \sum_{x\in T} \mu(-\Omega+x) = \mu(\Omega) N^k. 
$$
Therefore, 
$$
m \ge \frac{\mu(\Omega)N^k}{(N+d)^k}.
$$
Letting $N\to\infty$, we obtain $m\ge \mu(\Omega)$, whence $m\ge n+1$.

---

Concerning the measurability of the maps in question, it depends on how you enumerate $\Omega\cap[x]$: for some enumerations, the maps might be measurable, but they are not in general. It might be possible to apply measurable selection argument, but I should think.

Comment: On second thoughts : I think I will post in a separate question, the question of measurability. I am happy with your answer.